# Php form: select and jquery issue. How configure it properly?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I searched but still not found what I'm looking for. I have two separate forms that generate a final result, one for men, one for woman. They work in separate folder script as shown:

```
<form action="../folder1/index.php" METHOD="POST">
<p>Men: Put your name<br>
<input type="text" name="realname" size=25> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</p>
</form>
```

and

```
<form action="../folder2/index.php" METHOD="POST">
<p>Woman: Put your name<br>
<input type="text" name="realname" size=25> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</p>
</form>
```

How to "merge" them? Because I was using a method that uses jquery, but it goes in conflict with jquery of a wordpress plugin. I will use this into an iframe (I publish it into a wordpress page), but any tips for an alternative to avoid iframe (and use it inside a custom wordpress template) is welcome.
Thanks!

Edit: as suggested I'll try to explain better. I have two forms, one for men, one for woman, and each one launch/send variables to separate script into separate folders:

form1

```
<form action="../folder-1-with-script-for-MEN/index.php" METHOD="POST">
<p>Men: Put your name<br>
<input type="text" name="realname" size=25><input type="submit" value="Send"></p></form>
```

form2

```
<form action="../folder-2-with-script-for-WOMEN/index.php" METHOD="POST">
<p>Women: Put your name<br>
<input type="text" name="realname" size=25><input type="submit" value="Send"></p></form>
```

I need to use an unique form, like the following:

```
if selected realname is MEN then <form action="./folder-1-with-script-for-MEN/index.php" METHOD="POST">

if selected realname is WOMEN then <form action="./folder-2-with-script-for-WOMEN/index.php" METHOD="POST">
```

Actually I use the following script to do this function:

```
<script>

jQuery("#submit").on("click",function(){
    if(jQuery("#gender").val() == 1){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"http://./folder-1-with-script-for-MEN/index.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{realname:jQuery("#realname").val()},
            success: function(data){
                jQuery("#result").html(data);
            }
            });
    }
    else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"http://./folder-2-with-script-for-WOMEN/index.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{realname:jQuery("#realname").val()},
            success: function(data){
                jQuery("#result").html(data);
            }
            });
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

But do not work anymore cause of another plugin uses jquery. I'm looking for an alternative. Hope is clear now, thank for help

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be slightly confused, so maybe you could restate it.

However to 'merge them, you could do something like:

```
<form action="enter-name.php" METHOD="POST">
    <label>
       Please enter your name:
       <input type="text" name="realname" size=25>
    </label>

    <label>
       Male
       <input type="radio" value="male" name="sex">
    </label>

    <label>
       Female
       <input type="radio" value="female" name="sex">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

You can then handle the responses in the same page.